# How can I regenerate vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/config.xml?

Tags: magento2.3.1

I am making changes in my store configuration. They are changing in the database but they don't actually appear in the frontend. It appears this file- vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/config.xml is overriding them. Can I regenerate that file based off what is in the database?

Comment: Do not change file of the core directly, create a module that do what you want, then run **setup:upgrade** and **setup:di:compile**

Comment: My problem is that I want to require state for US orders. I can select that option in the backend, see it in the database, but it does not reflect on the frontend. I have done all the cache clearing, static content deploy, upgrade, and compile stuff. I shouldn't have to create a module to just require the state for the US right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do follow a tutorial similar to the following?

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/removedisable-magento-2-state-option/

Have you updated the config for every store scope? Have you cleared cache manually (delete var/cache)?

XML shouldn't override database.

Answer (score 0):

For other people that run across this problem. My database was missing a line after the upgrade. This fixed it-
UPDATE core_config_data SET scope = "stores", path = 'general/region/display_all', value=1 WHERE config_id=1243;